# Allow flatpak application to "Open with" other applications

Tags: permissions, files, installed-programs, flatpak

Is it possible to configure a Flatpak application so that it is able to send files ("Open with") to other programs? I am on Kubuntu.

For instance, I have Thunderbird installed as a Flatpak and would like to open PDF files directly in Okular. Currently, my only option is "System Handler" which does nothing. Alternately, what if the other program is also a Flatpak or a Snap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by upgrading to a new release of Kubuntu. Apparently in the older version, System Handler had not yet been fully implemented and was unable to hand-off files to other programs.